# (Actionscript 3) How to fix stack overflow in 2-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, overflow

In my program, two positions in a 2 dimensional array are considered connected if there is a path of equal integers you can follow along to connect those two positions. For example,

```
    [2, 2, 0, 0, 0
     0, 2, 1, 1, 0
     0, 2, 1, 0, 0
     0, 0, 1, 2, 0
     0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Array[4][1] and Array[1][3] are considered connected since you go from [4][1] to [1][3] by following that path of 1's. However, [0][0] is not connected to [3][3] since there is no path of 2's you can follow to go from one of these positions to the other. You can only follow a path of equal integers.

This is my code to determine whether or not the positions are connected: 
isConnectedTo(4, 1, 1, 3) is supposed to check whether [4][1] and [1][3] are connected and isConnectedTo(0, 0, 3, 3) is supposed to check whether [0][0] and [3][3] are connected.

```
function isConnectedTo(i1: int, j1: int, i2: int, j2: int): Boolean{
if(i1==i2 && j1==j2){
    return true;
}
if(boardArray[i1][j1]!=boardArray[i2][j2]){
    return false;
}
if(boardArray[i1][j1]==0 || boardArray[i2][j2]==0){
    return false;
}
if(j1==j2 && Math.abs(i1-i2)==1){
    return true;
}
if(i1==i2 && Math.abs(j1-j2)==1){
    return true;
}
if(i2-1>=0 && boardArray[i2-1][j2]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2-1, j2)){
    return true;
}
if(i2+1<boardArray.length && boardArray[i2+1][j2]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2+1, j2)){
    return true;
}
if(j2-1>=0 && boardArray[i2][j2-1]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2, j2-1)){
    return true;
}
if(j2+1<boardArray[0].length && boardArray[i2][j2+1]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2, j2+1)){
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

However, this code throws a Stack Overflow. Is there an easy way to fix this? Thanks, I will appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT: Okay, I tried using something like a pathfinder like how some of you suggested. It works perfectly except the game slows down every time the function throws "true". Am I doing it right?

```
function isConnectedTo(i1: int, j1: int, i2: int, j2: int): Boolean{
    for(var i:int=0; i<boardArray.length; i++){
        for(var j:int=0; j<boardArray[i].length; j++){
            counterValues[i][j]=-1;
        }
    }
    counterValues[i2][j2]=0;
    setCounterValues(i2, j2);
    return counterValues[i1][j1]>=0;
}
function setCounterValues(i:int, j:int): void{
    if(boardArray[i][j]==0){
        return;
    }
    if((i-1<0 || boardArray[i-1][j]!=boardArray[i][j] || counterValues[i-1]
[j]!=-1)
        &&(j-1<0 || boardArray[i][j-1]!=boardArray[i][j] || counterValues[i 
][j-1]!=-1)
        &&(i+1>=boardArray.length || boardArray[i+1][j]!=boardArray[i][j] || 
counterValues[i+1][j]!=-1)
        &&(j+1>=boardArray[i].length || boardArray[i][j+1]!=boardArray[i][j] 
|| counterValues[i][j+1]!=-1)){
        return;
    }
    if(i-1>=0 && boardArray[i-1][j]==boardArray[i][j] && counterValues[i-1]
[j]==-1){
        counterValues[i-1][j]=counterValues[i][j]+1;
        setCounterValues(i-1, j);
    }
    if(j-1>=0 && boardArray[i][j-1]==boardArray[i][j] && counterValues[i][j-
1]==-1){
        counterValues[i][j-1]=counterValues[i][j]+1;
        setCounterValues(i, j-1);
    }
    if(i+1<boardArray.length && boardArray[i+1][j]==boardArray[i][j] && 
counterValues[i+1][j]==-1){
        counterValues[i+1][j]=counterValues[i][j]+1;
        setCounterValues(i+1, j);
    }
    if(j+1<boardArray[i].length && boardArray[i][j+1]==boardArray[i][j] && 
counterValues[i][j+1]==-1){
        counterValues[i][j+1]=counterValues[i][j]+1;
        setCounterValues(i, j+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, the **Array** in your post is **not** 2-dimensional. It is just a regular 1-dimensional **Array** formatted with newlines. Second, the problem you are solving is a **pathfinding** problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) and cannot be solved by the bunch of **if**s. What if your source data is 1000x1000 rather than 5x5? The correct algorithm should work it out with no regard to the data size.

Comment: Yes, you should make your array two dimensional and implement a proper pathfinding (which isn't that hard, easier than to handle 100 if's on a larger map). Google for "A* pathfinding as3" - there are some libraries that are already doing what you need. The only thing you will have to adjust is that the pathfinding will look for the same number as in your first "tile"

Comment: @Organis Since the OP wasn't complaining of a ReferenceError, I'd guess that the array in the post was merely formatted for readability, not a direct copy-paste from their code.  Good points otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that 2-dimensional array in my post was not actually from my code. I just put that in as an example. I read the path finding article and it looks very simple and it looks like it would work very well. I am going to try it.

Comment: I tried something like the pathfinder. It works perfectly except every time it throws true, the game slows down. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: @GaryLuKOTH use the **@** symbol to address other User(s), otherwise they don't get notified.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the beginning of your function:

`trace("isConnectedTo: (" + i1 + "," + j1 + "), ("+ i2 + "," + j2 + ")");`

That yielded the following output:

```
isConnectedTo: (4,1), (1,2)
isConnectedTo: (4,1), (2,2)
isConnectedTo: (4,1), (1,2)
isConnectedTo: (4,1), (2,2)
isConnectedTo: (4,1), (1,2)
```

The `isConnectedTo` algorithm is running an infinite loop because it has no way of knowing that it already checked a given position.

One approach to fix this is to add the previous coordinates to the function call, and short-circuit the recursion if you're re-checking where you just came from (note the checks of form `m+/-1 != n` in the lines containing recursive calls):

```
private function isConnectedTo(i1: int, j1: int, i2: int, j2: int, i3:int = -1, j3:int = -1): Boolean {
    trace("isConnectedTo: (" + i1 + "," + j1 + "), ("+ i2 + "," + j2 + ")");
    if(i1==i2 && j1==j2){
        return true;
    }
    if(boardArray[i1][j1]!=boardArray[i2][j2]){
        return false;
    }
    if(boardArray[i1][j1]==0 || boardArray[i2][j2]==0){
        return false;
    }
    if(j1==j2 && Math.abs(i1-i2)==1){
        return true;
    }
    if(i1==i2 && Math.abs(j1-j2)==1){
        return true;
    }
    //Up 1 square
    if(i2-1>=0 && (i2-1 != i3) && boardArray[i2-1][j2]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2-1, j2, i2, j2)){
        return true;
    }
    //Down 1 square
    if(i2+1<boardArray.length && (i2+1 != i3) && boardArray[i2+1][j2]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2+1, j2, i2, j2)){
        return true;
    }
    //Left 1 square
    if(j2-1>=0 && (j2-1 != j3) && boardArray[i2][j2-1]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2, j2-1, i2, j2)){
        return true;
    }
    //Right 1 square
    if(j2+1<boardArray[0].length && (j2+1 != j3) && boardArray[i2][j2+1]==boardArray[i2][j2] && isConnectedTo(i1, j1, i2, j2+1, i2, j2)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another approach is to memo-ize your check:

```
private var visited:Dictionary = new Dictionary();          

private function isConnectedTo(i1: int, j1: int, i2: int, j2: int): Boolean {
    var statusKey:String = i2 + "_" + j2;
    trace("isConnectedTo: (" + i1 + "," + j1 + "), ("+ i2 + "," + j2 + ") ... " + visited[statusKey]);
    if (visited[statusKey]) {
        return false;
    }
    visited[statusKey] = true;
    //... rest of isConnectedTo
}
```

The latter approach short-circuits the recursion by simply returning "false" for any node already visited by the algorithm.

Comment: I tried your first code and it still throws an overflow. I am having trouble understanding what I am supposed to do with the second code.

Comment: ... just how big is your boardArray?  The second code block is intended to show how to memoize the algorithm; just add the stuff about `statusKey` to the beginning of your `isConnectedTo` function (and have the Dictionary available).  Also important - make sure you reset the dictionary between calls.

Comment: Exactly 12 X 6. I will try the dictionary one later though. Thanks.